# Combining conditional artifact download blocks in GitHub Actions

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two separate GitHub Actions blocks that download artifacts from a workflow based on the version specified by the user. I want to merge these two blocks into a single one. The only difference between the two blocks is that the **run_number** input is only included if the **inputs.my_artifact_version** is not set to "latest".

Here's the original code:

```
- name: Download The Latest Artifact Version
  if: inputs.my_artifact_version == 'latest'
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
  with:
    workflow: my_backup_workflow.yml
    workflow_conclusion: success
    branch: main
    name: ${{ env.MY_BACKUP_FOLDER }}
    path: output
    if_no_artifact_found: fail

- name: Download The Artifact Version [${{ inputs.my_artifact_version }}]
  if: inputs.my_artifact_version != 'latest'
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
  with:
    workflow: my_backup_workflow.yml
    workflow_conclusion: success
    branch: main
    run_number: ${{ inputs.my_artifact_version }}
    name: ${{ env.MY_BACKUP_FOLDER }}
    path: output
    if_no_artifact_found: fail
```

I want to merge these two blocks into a single one that will automatically detect whether to include the run_number input or not.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just looked at its [implementation](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact/blob/master/main.js), looks like you may use something like this in one step: `run_number: ${{ inputs.my_artifact_version != 'latest' && inputs.my_artifact_version || '' }}`. Please test this on your side without `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine both steps, you may use something like this in one step without an `if`:

```yaml
run_number: ${{ (inputs.my_artifact_version != 'latest') && inputs.my_artifact_version || '' }}
```